# Render Node API data in HTML

Tags: node.js

I have been following this tutorial: https://howtocreateapps.com/fetch-and-display-json-html-javascript/

And I have this script in my HTML page:

```
...
<script>
    fetch('http://ec2-22-222-22-22.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080/fish')
        .then(function (response) {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(function (data) {
            appendData(data);
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log('error: ' + err);
        });

    function appendData(data) {
        var mainContainer = document.getElementById("myData");
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var div = document.createElement("div");
            div.textContent = '>> ' + data[i].timestamp + ' ' + data[i].date + ' ' + data[i].time + ' ' + data[i].airt_c + ' ' + data[i].rh + ' ' + data[i].dewp + ' ' + data[i].prec + ' ' + data[i].slrr + ' ' + data[i].parr + ' ' + data[i].netr + ' ' + data[i].bar + ' ' + data[i].wspd + ' ' + data[i].wdir + ' ' + data[i].gspd + ' ' + data[i].s10t;
            mainContainer.appendChild(div);
        }
    }
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="bg">
  <div id="myData"></div>
</div>
```

The table it's trying to display is from this SQL table:

```
      timestamp      | date  | time  | airt_c | rh | dewp | prec | slrr | parr | netr | bar  | wspd | wdir | gspd | s10t 
---------------------+-------+-------+--------+----+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------
 2020-03-14 12:03:49 | 03-14 | 11:00 | 6.4    | 47 | -4.1 | 0.0  | 765  | 1793 | 417  | 1022 | 3.8  | 272  | 10.0 | 4.0
```

My `index.js` file (running on an ec2 -- a different host than the HTML page), looks like this:

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const app = express()
const port = 8080
const db = require('./queries')


app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
  })
)

app.get('/', (request, response) => {
  response.json({ info: 'Node.js, Express, and Postgres API' })
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`App running on port ${port}.`)
})

app.get('/fish', db.getFish)
```

My `queries.js` looks like this:

```
const Pool = require('pg').Pool
const pool = new Pool({
  user: 'user',
  host: 'database-1.sdsad2233.rds.amazonaws.com',
  database: 'db',
  password: 'pass',
})


const getFish = (request, response) => {
  pool.query('SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 10', (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
      throw error
    }
    response.status(200).json(results.rows)
  })
}

module.exports = {
  getFish,
}
```

How can I display the result of that query inside of my HTML page?

--

EDIT

Someone mentioned that the issue might be because the HTML page is on a different host and does not have HTTPS.

I am trying to create the HTML in a separate .js file on the same ec2 server, but hitting an error.

My code:

```
var http=require("http");
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {});
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
    });
});
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
    });
    response.write("This is Test Message.");
    response.end();
});
server.listen(8082);



fetch('/fish')
        .then(function (response) {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(function (data) {
            appendData(data);
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log('error: ' + err);
        });

    function appendData(data) {
        var mainContainer = document.getElementById("myData");
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var div = document.createElement("div");
            div.textContent = '>> ' + data[i].timestamp + ' ' + data[i].date + ' ' + data[i].time + ' ' + data[i].airt_c + ' ' + data[i].rh + ' ' + data[i].dewp + ' ' + data[i].prec + ' ' + data[i].slrr + ' ' + data[i].parr + ' ' + data[i].netr + ' ' + data[i].bar + ' ' + data[i].wspd + ' ' + data[i].wdir + ' ' + data[i].gspd + ' ' + data[i].s10t;
            mainContainer.appendChild(div);
        }
    }
```

The error:

```
$ node reality.js 
/home/ubuntu/riapi/webpage.js:19
fetch('/fish')
^

ReferenceError: fetch is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/riapi/webpage.js:19:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:188:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:609:3
```

Comment: What happens when you use something like [postman](https://www.postman.com/) or curl to make a request to your API?

Comment: @HowlingFantods - when I `curl` from Terminal, I correctly get the records back.

Comment: Chrome's developer tools can be very helpful in situations like this. Open the console (Command+Option+J (Mac) or Control+Shift+J (Windows, Linux, Chrome OS)) and see if there are any errors. If not, try adding a 'break point' (on a new line, add `debugger;`) in your code that will let you inspect the value of different variables at a given point in your code. I would start inside the `appendData` function.

Comment: @HowlingFantods - I found this, which I am attempting to decode: `Access to fetch at 'http://ec2-22-222-22-22.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080/fish' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two problems:

1. You are mixing server-side code with client-side code  `fetch` and
   DOM APIs are only available in the browser not in nodejs, so when
   you are trying to access the fetch you get the first error `fetch is
   not defined`
2. you didn't enable CORS requests in the server-side
   code, simply add those two lines to your index.js (server-side code)

```js
    const cors = require('cors')
    app.use(cors())
```

so your final server-side code should look like

```js
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const cors = require('cors') //you need to `npm install cors` first

const app = express()
const port = 8080
const db = require('./queries')


app.use(cors()) //enable cors requests
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
  })
)

app.get('/', (request, response) => {
  response.json({ info: 'Node.js, Express, and Postgres API' })
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`App running on port ${port}.`)
})

app.get('/fish', db.getFish)
```